# Who else can reply to an approval request beside the designated approver?

Tags: administration, approval-process

For the standard Salesforce approval processes, who else can approve a request besides the designated approver?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

**Roles**

<strike>If you've set the approval to "anybody from the Queue" make sure you're OK with who's in the Queue exactly. Easiest is to click "view all members". Roughly speaking expect that all managers of your queue members (all the way to CEO or whatever is your top role) will have access too.</strike>

I honestly don't know if it also works when an User is set as the actual approver (can his Manager do it? can somebody higher in the hierarchy do it?)

Edit: Ralph has tested this thoroughly and while higher Roles do become indirect queue members - this fact alone doesn't mean they can approve. Explicit access must be given or "modify all" permission for the object.

**Profiles / Permission sets**

As pointed out by Jesse - anybody with "modify all data".

**Last but not least**

User's own delegated approver, if anybody was set. That's for "what to do when I'm on holidays". Delegated approvers don't get notifications (unless they wish to do so, they can set it on their user record) and don't see the requests on home page. As far as I know if hey don't want spam - easiest for them is to periodically check reports.

Sysadmins (actually "modify all data" again) can view Administrative -> All pending approval requests
Delegates can view Activity -> My delegated approval requests.

Comment: So i tried out the queue approach and only the members, not their managers are users higher in the role hierarchy, could approve.  Are you sure about that one?

Comment: Regarding modify all data, ran some tests and you can approve anything as long as you have modify all for the particular object

Comment: It was at my previous client's place so I don't have access anymore but I recall that if Queue was approving - people higher could too. They weren't getting email notifications (that was sent only to "regular" members) but if they stumbled upon record in approval they were able to. I'm almost 100% sure they didn't have "modify all" on the object. And the approver was just a queue, nothing like "My Manager" or "let me choose manually". I will try to contact old colleagues.

Comment: pretty sure on this one, i setup a test approval process, assigned it to a queue with someone lower in the hierarchy, and then logged in as their manager (couldn't approve), and a user higher in the role hierarchy (couldn't approve)

Comment: Thx @Ralph, updated! You're 100% right... The person with rogue approval I had to inspect some time ago was higher in the food chain but also had "Modify all" on the object...

Answer (score 4):

System Administrators can approve the records as well. I believe it is based on the Modify All permission on the object with the approval process.

Comment: anyone else besides administrators?

Answer (score 2):

https://login.salesforce.com/help/doc/en/approvals_change_approval_user_pref.htm

A delegated user can also approve or reject .he cannot reassign but he can approve or reject